# How can I delete a hive database without using hive terminal?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have a multinode Hadoop cluster setup with two nodes(one master node and one slave node). Each node with 8GB RAM.

I have also configured hive on the master node. Everything is up and working.

`Nodemanager` and `Datanode` are working on the slave node.

`ResourceManager`, `Namenode`, and `SecondaryNamenode` are also working on the master node.

I am able to access the hive terminal as well, but I am not able to drop the database through the `drop database databaseName;` command. It is not showing any error but has been stuck for more than an hour... Three tables have size `10000 * 20`. I thought these may be causing the speed issues, so I wanted to delete the database, but am not able to delete via `drop database` command, so is there any way to do it directly by deleting any files?

I have tried to access `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` to delete the database directly, but this directory is completely empty.

Similar slow behavior can be observed with other hive commands as well. I am just able to run one command i.e. `show databases;`. And this command is also taking around 70 secs to execute.

I am a beginner in the Big Data domain so, any help would be appreciated. If I need to add any configuration file for reference please do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing via HDFS?

The following command should display all of your databases:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive
```

*Note: /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive must be your `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`*

With -rm you can remove it:

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/yourDatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check the metastore.log file if there is an exception occurred.

You can manually delete the hdfs directory (recursive remove) of the particular table followed by drop table if exists (table_name)